# Zone update on validation?

Tags: tapestry

In my Tapestry page I have a zone I'd like to update when I call a validation method. Is this possible? Can zones only be updated when an event is called? Can I create an event and catch it in the same class that would allow me to update a zone?

I thought this might work but it doesn't....

```
void onValidateFromIssuingOfficerTextField(Long forename) throws ValidationException {
    if (!forename=null) {
        updateZone();
        throw new ValidationException("You must supply a Forename");
    }
}

Object updateZone(){
    return myZone.getBody()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/form

seems like is what you need